# MySQL: How to find which user login with a wrong password

Tags: mysql, linux

I occasionally get 『unblock with mysqladmin flush-hosts』error message when connecting mysql server. The sad thing is, I don't know which process or which user is causing this. Is there a way to find out which user is trying to log in to mysql server with a wrong password? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Oh. I found this. 
    https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/
Auditing will get it done.